# Windows Workflow 4.0 Service Reference not showing in toolbox

Tags: windows, workflow, toolbox

I've created a simple workflow service app (WF1), then I've added a windows form client to my solution with another workflow activity (WF2) within. Then I've added the proper service reference to WF1.
When I try to use my service reference to add a message call from WF2 (windows forms) to WF1 (workflow service app)... there insn't any items in the toolbox that represents my service ref WF1! It is  missing. No luck trying to add it... I'm lost. Any ideas?

Comment: Have to tried with "Chosse Items..." by right clicking your toolbox and browsing to find WF1?

Comment: Yes, when I select the assembly, it tells me that it's no valid.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit better what are you trying to do? I understand you want to build WorkflowServices, but I don’t understand why you want to use the WorkflowService as an activity in other Workflow. Do you want to test your WorkflowService? Instead of using it as an activity, wouldn’t it be better if you add a Service Reference to your winForm client and consume the WorkflowService as a WCF service? I’m just assuming that is what you need to do.

Comment: I need to access a workflow (part of a workflow service app) from ANOTHER workflow activity shipped with a windows form app. Just use it to accomplish some kind of code reuse.

Comment: I've see code examples that works in this way, the only difference is that the client app is a console workflow app. This is relevant somehow? Thanks!

Comment: Oh! And YES, I've added the Service Reference in my winforms app to my Workflow service app. Even son I don't see it in the toolbox. If I write a console app as client, add the service reference, THEN the toolbox shows it for use.... Outside the console app...nothing!

Comment: I want to reproduce this behaviour: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/ff859495 (see the second scenario: lib against console app) but with a windows form app instead of a console app. ¿It's even possible?

Answer (score 0):

After watching the video and based on your second comment above, I believe that it is not necessary to try to use the WorkflowService as an activity inside other workflow, the same way the video shows. Realize that, in the video, he is only making a call to one of the service operations. The Workflow console template project allows calling the service operation in that easy way by wrapping the operation in an Activity, thus freeing you from having to instantiate a proxy client. There are other ways to achieve the same result.

What I would do: Add the Service Reference in your WinForms client to the WorkflowServiceApp, WF1 (you’ve already done this). Inside the second workflow (WF2), instantiate a proxy of the type of WF1 and call the operations the service exposes directly, like you would call any normal service operation if you were not inside a workflow. It is basically consuming a WCF service. One option will be to create a variable of the type of your service, instantiate a new reference in, for example, an Assign activity, creating a variable of the type of the result of the service and finally making a call to the service, either in other Assign or InvokeMethod activity.

First Assign activity:

```
proxy = New WF1Client() //That has to be the name of you client as created by the Service Reference
```

Second Assign activity:

```
Result = proxy.MyMethod(...) //The call to the operation. You would have to create the variables to hold the result and any input parameters you wish to pass to the operation.
```

That would be straight forward. You won't need to use the service itself as an Activity.

If still you need to make it one single activity to use inside the designer or share between other workflows, create a [Code Activity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489453.aspx), make the call to the service operation in it (instantiate proxy, set inputs, etc.), compile and your code activity will appear in the toolbox so you can use it in WF2. Furthermore, if you create a ClassLibrary, and implement your activities, either the ones that come with WF or [custom activities](http://www.develop.com/wf4) there, you can re-use them in different workflow projects by referencing the ClassLibrary. If you have control over the development of WF1 you could use this approach to re-use your activities.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for this response! I also can use the messaging activities shipped with VS2010 and call the service as any other web service right?

Comment: Yes. The messaging activities allow a Workflow to be exposed as a WCF service. The Receive activity is just like a WCF service contract with a service operation ([1](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/wfprerelease/thread/a077a156-bd06-438b-9b90-ec1024b12165)), therefore turning the WorkflowService in a WCF service you can consume as any other regular WCF service.